# what is the best pratice for Java to encapsulate thread-safe code

Tags: java, multithreading, encapsulation

Suppose I have one ClassA whose responsibility is to provide thread-safe API for external usage. and some ClassA API has to invoke some method from another ClassB to fulfill some logic (suppose the ClassB's method is stateless and thread-safe). However, ClassB and ClassA can not be merged as a single class due business logic. For example as following code snippet. Is there better way to accomplish this? of course, I could use finer-granularity concurrency control for ClassA such as synchronized block, concurrent lock-free data structures.

Thanks!

```
public class ClassA{
   public synchronized void method1(ClassB cb){
     //do internal stuff1
     cb.printAlog();
     //do internal stuff2
   }
   public synchronized void method2(){
     //do internal stuff3
   }
   ......
}

public class ClassB{
   public void printALog(){
     //....
   }
   ......
}
```

Comment: If `ClassB` is stateless, why don't you inject it as a field of `ClassA`?

Answer (score 2):

The question doesn't make sense. If class B is stateless you don't need to synchronize calling it at all. You just need to synchronize whatever needs synchronization in class A: about which you have provided precisely zero information. Class B is 100% irrelevant to this question.

Comment: classes definitely can be thread-safe, for example immutable classes

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood the question, you are wandering about guarding the non-threadsafe code with thread-safe class. At this point of view the code you provided is completely legal, as soon as you don't expose classB in some way, which makes it possible to break the contract of classA.

This design is also described in [Java concurrency in practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) very well.